Problems with Windows Hello for Business in hybrid Cloud Trust scenario, but only on Windows 10
So I went through the process of deploying WHFB. I set up all the prereqs (as far as I know) following the Cloud Trust deployment guide. I added four test machines to the test OU with the appropriate WHFB GPO applied. Two of these machines, which are running Windows 11, worked flawlessly. On next boot we were able to enroll and everything is working fine. However, I'm now testing the two Windows 10 (22H2) machines and they still show "This setting is managed by your administrator" and cannot be enrolled. I have confirmed with RSOP that the policy did apply. When I check the event viewer, I see the following events (On both machines):



LEVEL
Summary




Info
Windows Hello for Business prerequisites check started.


Success
Windows Hello for Business successfully completed the remote desktop prerequisite check.


Success
The Primary Account Primary Refresh Token prerequisite check completed successfully.


Success
The device registration prerequisite check completed successfully.


Info
Windows Hello for Business certificate enrollment configurations:Certificate Enrollment Method: RACertificate Required for On-Premise Auth: true


Success
Windows Hello for Business is enabled.


Error
Windows Hello for Business post-logon provisioning is not enabled.


Success
The device meets Windows Hello for Business hardware requirements.


Error
The Secondary Account Primary Refresh Token prerequisite check failed.


Error
Windows Hello for Business failed to locate a certificate registration authority.


Error
Windows Hello for Business prerequisites check failed.Error: 0x1



And then that entire series of events repeats like 3 times.
The devices show as Hybrid-Joined. AD Sync is working fine. I don't see any obvious problems. I don't understand why it's even looking for a CA since I'm using Cloud Trust and the two Win11 devices are working fine (and do not show any of these errors in their event logs).
Any guidance appreciated.

I suspect some GPO that come into play versus your settings you push via Intune. Does the Windows 10 do the same behavior if outside of the domain and just joined cloud ?

I haven't really tested that in this environment, but Windows Hello is available by default in a non-domain environment as far as I know. Also, I'm not pushing anything via Intune other than Bitlocker and OneDrive settings. This company only recently went hybrid. Nothing that would affect this AFAIK.

I recheck your error message and I suspect your computer miss some settings.
As we talked you have no Intune policy so these would be these GPO;
Important to make sure these 3 settings are set in the minimum to make sure WHfB use the Cloud Kerberos Thust method.
It's a Computer GPO, except one which can set set in Computer or User.
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Hello for Business
Use Windows Hello for Business - Enabled
or
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Hello for Business
Use Windows Hello for Business - Enabled
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Hello for Business
Use cloud Kerberos trust for on-premises authentication - Enabled
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Hello for Business
Use a hardware security device - Enabled
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/deploy/hybrid-cloud-kerberos-trust?WT.mc_id=EM-MVP-5004117&tabs=gpo#tabpanel_1_gpo

"Use cloud Kerberos trust for on-premises authentication - Enabled"  This option does not exist in the Group Policy Management Editor. I instead enabled 'Use certificate for on-prem authentication". Prior to enabling that it would let me enroll in WHFB but when you try to use it it would just say "Temporarily unavailable". As soon as I enabled "Use certificate" it started working on the first two test machines.
This is obviously weird though, as I'm not (knowingly) using a CA. Why don't I have the Kerberos option?

Hmm, do I need to do all this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-authentication-passwordless-security-key-on-premises#install-the-azureadhybridauthenticationmanagement-module
And if so, why did it work on the first two machines?

@THEJOATMON If it's not there, get the newer ADMX (install latest admx for windows 1022H2) and install it into your policy store to have the new settings by GPO. (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=104677)

@THEJOATMON Yes you need to make the 4 command. It create a Kerberos server local to your AD, that is in sync with your tenant. A good article to do it; https://msendpointmgr.com/2023/03/04/cloud-kerberos-trust-part-2/

@THEJOATMON For the why it worked on the Windows 11, I dont know, it maybe detected your online kerberos server and used it, but if it worked, try from these computer to naviguate to a server share to test out, like \server\share, it should not work as you DC can't usually decode the WHfB token from the computer for the SSO if you havent have done the 4 step.

@THEJOATMON btw, remove the setting to use the certificate. It's the old way WHfB was checking with your onprem DC, was way more compex to install with the CA. Kinda why Microsoft did the 4 step, and the Cloud Trust's model, more easy to implement, but as you can guess you really need to set the computer in cloud trust.

Okay I removed the "Use certificate" setting. I walked through adding the kerberos server object. Get-AzureADKerberosServer now shows a user. However, the Group Policy Manager still doesn't show the "User Kerberos..." policy.

@THEJOATMON To test, use gpedits.msc and edit the local group policy of the computer, as else like I told to make a GPO with that settings you need the latest ADMX.

@THEJOATMON or to make it more simple, "You can copy the ADMX and ADML files from a Windows client that supports cloud Kerberos trust to their respective language folder on your Group Policy management server. Windows Hello for Business settings are in the Passport.admx and Passport.adml files."

Thank you. I've never done anything like that before, but I'm sure with ChatGPT's help we can get through it! :)  Thanks again.

That fixed both machines immediately! I'm baffled how it worked on the first two with the TOTALLY wrong settings.  ¯\(ツ)/¯

To be clear, the problem was the wrong "trust" setting. I had to install the updated Passport.admx file on the DC and then enable the Cloud Trust GPO setting. This immediately fixed the issue and didn't even require a reboot (just a gpupdate). Thank you again.

And of course, all the event log errors make sense now. If it hadn't been for 2 machines working and the correct setting just NOT being there, I probably wouldn't gone down the wrong path at all.
